# Doubt in energy of electron in first shell of hydrogen atom

Tags: special-relativity, energy, atomic-physics, mass-energy, hydrogen

Let us calculate the energy of the electron in the first shell of the hydrogen atom. Since hydrogen is a single electron species we can use Bohr's postulates. The kinetic energy (KE) of an electron in the first shell  is given by

$$KE=\frac{m e^{4}}{8 (1)^{2} h^{2} \varepsilon_{0}^{2}}$$

The potential energy (PE) of the electron in the first shell and nucleus system is given by

$$PE=-\frac{m e^{4}}{4 
(1)^{2} h^{2} \varepsilon_{0}^{2}}$$

The total energy of electron in the first shell is given by
$$E_{n}=KE+PE$$
$$\begin{array}{ll}\Rightarrow & E_{n}=\frac{m e^{4}}{8 (1)^{2} h^{2} \varepsilon_{0}^{2}}-\frac{m e^{4}}{4 (1)^{2} h^{2} \varepsilon_{0}^{2}} \\ \Rightarrow & E_{n}=\frac{-m e^{4}}{8 (1)^{2} h^{2} \varepsilon_{0}^{2}}\end{array}$$

Putting values of all the constants we get

$$E_{1} = -13.6 \mathrm{eV}$$

Now let us calculate the energy of the electron in the first shell of hydrogen atom using another formula. I studied in my physics class that the total energy of any particle is given by

$$E=K+m c^{2}$$

We can find the kinetic energy of the electron by using the velocity of the electron obtained by Bohr's postulates. Thus:

$$E=K+m c^{2}=\frac{m c^{2}}{\sqrt{1-v^{2} / c^{2}}}$$

$$E=\frac{(9.109×10^{-31})(3×10^{8})^{2}}{\sqrt{1-(2.188×10^{6})^{2} / (3×10^{8})^{2}}}$$

$$E_{1} = 512394.87802\mathrm{eV}$$

Why are the energies coming out to be different? Can someone please point out my mistake? Have I done any mistake somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

The higher value you got includes the electrons rest mass energy. If you subtract that the answers match.

$$512394.878 - \frac{(9.109×10^{-31})(3×10^{8})^{2}}{1.6×10^{-19}} = 13.628eV$$

Comment: What is the term that you have subtracted from the energy of the electron?

Comment: the expression $\frac{m c^{2}}{\sqrt{1-v^{2} / c^{2}}}$ includes the electrons rest mass energy as well as any kinetic energy.  The term subtracted is the electrons rest mass, converted into energy with $E=mc^2$ and then converted into electron-volts

Comment: So, if someone asks that what is the total energy of an electron in the first shell of hydrogen atom, which would be the correct answer - $512394.87802 eV$ or $-13.6 eV$? Shouldn't the rest mass of the electron also be accounted for while calculating the total energy of the electron?

Comment: Yes, if you include the rest-mass in *total*, then the answer would then be the electron rest mass $510990.6$ (looked up on the internet) add $-13.6$ giving $510977 eV$

Comment: My question is if someone asks you what is the total energy of an electron in the first shell of the hydrogen atom what would you say : $512394.87802 eV$ or $-13.6 eV$?